# Fabric Crashlytics Beta deploy fails: Project is inactive

Tags: android, crashlytics, fastlane, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I am having a react-native app with the bundle com.name.dev.app. I added Fabric/Crashlytics to both iOS and Android and use Fabric Crashlytics Beta for internal distribution. I see both Apps in the Fabric dashboard and when building a release build I can see the crashes in the respective apps's dashboard. This worked for about 7 days.

Now, when trying to upload an APK to Beta via the Android Studio Fabric Plugin or via our Fastlane CI Pipeline, I am getting an error saying:

```
WARN - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the distribution. Project applicationname is inactive
Exception in thread "main" com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Distribution upload failed.
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:667)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.main(DeveloperTools.java:273)
Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it had a problem uploading the distribution.Project applicationname is inactive
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:91)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:665)
    ... 2 more
```

I removed the Android app from Fabric and tried to recreate it. That failed, so I had to reach out to Crashlytics via Twitter and someone was so kind and manually re-activated the app again for Android. Crash collection still works on both platform and uploading new IPA files to the iOS is flawless. But I cannot upload an APK to the Android app.

I am a bit clueless. The project ist kind of active as it receives crashes but doesn't allow me to add APK to Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks. If you get this 'inactive' error, you will need to contact support[at]fabric.io with your package name or bundle ID. We will need to manually activate the app on our side.

Comment: I already did and the team said it activated it. However, it is not solved because they activated a wrong bundle identifier and now Beta is uploading it into a different app than it collects the crashes. Unfortunately, the support is not very responsive. Hope to get it solved soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now thanks to the wonderful support at Crashlytics/Fabric. So the solution is the following. First of all, the support had to manually enable the project. Best way to reach out is via email or twitter. After this has been done, I had to comment out/remove the following line on my Android app build.gradle:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    // manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'**
}
```

Obviously Crashlytics is no able to find the AndroidManifest by itself and parsing it correctly, so your App ends up in the right App in your Fabric Dashboard.